# Optimizing sums of log det

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, clustering

I have a set of points $S$ which have to be clustered into $K$ cluster say, $S_k$, by minimizing the following function:

$J = - \sum_{i=1}^{K} \log \det( \mathbf{I} + H_i H_i^T)$,

Where $H_i$ is the matrix formed by taking the columns of points in cluster $i$. Note that $S = \cup S_k$ and $S_k \cap S_j = \emptyset$, if $k \neq j$.  We know the number clusters $K$. How do I optimize such function?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you show what you have tried to solve this problem?

Comment: @Hrodelbert Thanks. The $\log \det$ function that I have written is submodular in the columns of $H_i$ but this is useful only if I want to maximize just one matrix $H_i$ and not the sum present here. Since, it is the same set of points which can change clusters its not clear how to optimize this sum.

Comment: Also there are techniques for solving the $\max \det$ function but it does not include the sum as shown here.

Comment: I see. I would say a first remark is that the different $H_i$'s are completely independent, which means that you should be able to restrict your attention to one term in the sum at a time.

Comment: No, they are not. Because if I remove a point from a cluster I will add it to some other cluster. So we cannot do this term wise optimization.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you want. Maybe it would be useful if you could include some more details in your question, that makes it easier for others to understand what you want: in particular, do all the clusters have to have the same number of points?

Comment: Clustering is a notoriously difficult problem, because the objective function ($J$ in your case) is usually nonconvex. In your case it is even difficult to compute objective function values due to the determinant. What is the dimension of the $H_i$?

Comment: you can take dimensions of $H_i$ to be $p \times m$ where $m$ is the number of elements of the cluster and $p$ is the dimension of each vector.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do it efficiently or exactly? Technically you have a mixed-integer convex MAXDET problem, so it can be solved using branch-and-bound applied on a convex semidefinite MAXDET problems.

This is the model in the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP (disclaimer, developed by me), which has a rudimentary mixed-integer SDP solver. To solve the relaxations, the SDP solver SDPT3 is required, as it is the only available MAXDET solver

```
% Generate some clusters
K = 4;
N = 12;
centers = randn(2,K);
H = repmat(centers,1,N/K) + randn(2,N)*.1;

% c(i,j) row j belong to cluster i
c = binvar(K,N,'full')
Model = [sum(c,1)==1];
objective = 0;
for i = 1:K
    objective = objective + logdet(eye(2) + H*diag(c(i,:))*H');
end
ops=sdpsettings('solver','bnb','bnb.solver','sdpt3')
optimize(Model,-objective,ops)
value(c)
```

This is the exact brute-force solution, and definitely not the way you want to approach this if you want to go for efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, I want to solve it efficiently, I am happy with an approximate solution.

Comment: OK Are you sure about the merits of this function for clustering. The planar well separated data used in the example above is not clustered in any sensible way in the optimal solution.

Comment: This kind of clustering might appear in sensor networks, and it is not really distance based clustering so a plot will not be good way to interpret this. Also, I am not able to run the code you provided I run into errors at `sdpsettings`.

Comment: Ok, figured it wasn't simple planar clustering. What happens in sdpsettings? For further YALMIP issues, you might want to use the YALMIP specific forum on google groups